# Arranging NSarray like 1-5, 5-10, 10-15 in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I want to arrange a NSarray which contains names in a UItableView like:

**Top 5**

Ryan

John

Roy

Amela

Pat

**5-10**

Goslin

Ted

Mike

Justin

Rambo

Timber

**10-15**

...

...

**15-20**

...

...

**20-25**

...

...

Wondering what should I use to hold the title, viewForHeaderInSection or just cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: your array has all values means 1--n numbers or else u need to call 1 -5 when user reach the 5th index u need to load the another 6 - 10 data

Comment: You also can use `-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`

Comment: What has the title, and much of the text, got to do with your question?

Comment: @trojanfoe: didn't you understand my question?

Comment: Yes; you want to know which `UITableView` delegate method to use.  So why the title about `NSArray`?

Comment: @trojanfoe : Actually I wanted to make the tittle more readable. By the way what do you suggest?

Answer (score 5):

Just use `-viewForHeaderInSection:` or `-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`

it will make your code much more readable, because using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` your code will have indexPath offsets, and you will need to make additional calculations for catching selected row.